# Change Laravel log level for queued job attempted too many times exception

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I would like to change the way queue exceptions of type "A queued job has been attempted too many times. The job may have previously timed out." are logged.

I tried adding the following to the `\Exception\Handler::report()` method but I still see these showing up as ERROR in my logs.

```
public function report(Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Queue\MaxAttemptsExceededException) {
         try {
             $logger = $this->container->make(LoggerInterface::class);
         } catch (Exception $ex) {
             throw $exception; // throw the original exception
         }

         $logger->warning($e);

         return;
    }

    parent::report($exception);
}
```

I also get alerts to a Slack channel (the most annoying part) for these when the min level is ERROR. I want to transform it to a WARNING so I prevent that from happening.

```
$slackHandler = new SlackHandler(
    config('slack.api_token'),
    config('slack.channel'),
    'Laravel Error',
    true,
    null,
    Logger::ERROR,
    true,
    false,
    true
);
```

Admittedly this is similar to another question I asked, but I appear to have implemented it wrong.